# Proxy address is being replaced with /dev/cdrom

Tags: debian, git, proxy, http-proxy

I have a weird issue that I can't seem to find an answer for.

When I enter:

`git config --global http.proxy http://{username}:{password}@{proxy address}:{port}/`

It returns an error:

`git config --global http.proxy http://{username}:mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom{password}@{proxy address}:{port}/`

I do have an `!1` in the password field that seems to be getting replaced and the rest of the password is echoing.

I had a look is `!1` is a shortcut to `/dev/cdrom` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in an interactive shell, `!` is the last command line, and it's quite possible `!1` is the first word of it, etc. (Can you tell it's not a feature I use?) Just put the whole proxy url in single quotes like

```
git config --global http.proxy 'http://{username}:{password}@{proxy address}:{port}/'
```

(You'll see similar effects with `$` and anything that's a shell wildcard like `?` or  `*`: the command line doesn't know what's a file name parameter.)

Comment: I thought I tried that but I realise I was using `"` not `'` and it was still returning the same error